# Url forwarding with zone file

Tags: dns

I want to forward a url so that if you type www.example.com in the address bar, you are forwarded to www.test.com/test.php.

What I have done is added a cname record to my zone file.

So I have:

```
www  IN CNAME www.test.com/test.php.
```

This isn't getting the job done.

I have read quite a bit and am still having trouble grasping how the whole dns process works.  My understanding is that a CNAME will just cause your domain to use another domains zone file.  If this is the case, then a CNAME wouldn't be what I am looking for.

If anybody could point me in the right direction, or give me a brief overview of the process in url forwarding, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You confuse **DNS** with **URL forwarding**. All you may have in a zone file is

```
www.example.com.  IN CNAME www.test.com.
```

`www.test.com` is a **domain name**, `www.test.com/test.php` is a **URL**.

having this CNAME have **exactly** same effect as having an "A" record for www.example.com  pointing to the same IP address as www.test.com - youyr browser will first look at this CNAME, then get an IP address for www.example.com, then browser will send to that IP address, HTTP request for www.example.com **(!)**.

URL forwarding done on a webserver, on www.test.com webserver you may define a virtual host www.example.com (NOT www.test.com), which may run your test.php or redirect from / to /test.php.

Or on www.example.com webserver you may setup a HTTP 303 redirect from www.example.com to www.test.com/test.php and then you don't use a CNAME.

Though somewhat unordered but hope it helps.

Comment: I have my dns server, call it 1.1.1.1.  I have a webserver, 2.2.2.2.  www.example.com is not on this a webserver, it is currently just a domain.

So could I:
in the zone file, create "www IN A 2.2.2.2.", then on 2.2.2.2 set up a HTTP 303 redirect from example.com to test.com/test.php?

Answer (score 0):

The answer up is right absolutely, but i think the solution is as this:

Really it's easy with redirect.center

If you want create a CNAME as :

www.proof.com IN CNAME www.proof-two.com/path/index.htm

using redirect.center your CNAME look as canonical mode as:

www.proof.com IN CNAME www.proof-two.com.opts-slash.path.opts-slash.index.htm.redirect.center.

Now if you want redirect to https website you can add this option:

www.proof.com IN CNAME www.proof-two.com.opts-slash.path.opts-slash.index.htm.opts-https.redirect.center.

Now you can create a CNAME with the canonical mode with slash in your destiny page.